# Node.js mysql db connects after the query

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to write a database manager module in node.js for some of the common queries I am going to use in a server app. I want to test the module. However, my code does not connect to the database before I do the queries. How can I arrange my code in such way, it connects to db before the queries, not after them?

#### Code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var conn = mysql.createConnection(
{
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'mydb'  
});

conn.connect(function(error)
{
    if ( error) throw error;
    console.log('->connected to database');
});

// user as json
getUserData = function(username)
{
    conn.query('SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = \"' + username + 
    '\"' , function (error, result, fields)
    {
        if (error) throw error;
        return result; 
    });
}

console.log('result->' + JSON.stringify(getUserData('eness')));

conn.end();
```

#### Output:

```
result->undefined
->connected to database
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getUserData()` has nothing to return. Returning `result` from the query's callback function does not make it the return value of `getUserData()` as callback is executed **asynchronously**.

**You can't return from an *asynchronous* function call inside a *synchronous* function.**

If you move the `console.log()` line into the callback, you will see the correct output:

```
getUserData = function(username) {
    conn.query('SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = \"' + username + '\"' , function (error, result, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log('result->' + JSON.stringify(result));
    });
}

getUserData('eness');
conn.end();
```

If you don't want to put the logic in the query's callback (separate query and business logic):

```
getUserData = function(username, cb) {
    conn.query('SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = \"' + username + '\"' , function (error, result, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        cb(result)
    });
}

getUserData('eness', function(result) {
    console.log('result->' + JSON.stringify(result));
});
conn.end();
```

Welcome to [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) :) Now consider using [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the async nature of node.js , the code after `conn.connect` will not wait for that connection to complete to execute `getUserData`, therefore since the `getUserData` operation is not waiting for the connection to happen before executing you're probably having this error. Try the following to fix this for only testing purposes. And if youre using the `getUserData` function connected to a REST endpoint this will not occur since connection happens when the nodejs app is starting.

```
conn.connect(function(error)
    {
        if ( error) throw error;
        else console.log('result->' + JSON.stringify(getUserData('eness')));
        console.log('->connected to database');
    });

function getUserData(username)
{
    conn.query('SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = \"' + username + 
    '\"' , function (error, result, fields)
    {
        if (error) throw error;
        return result; 
    });
}

conn.end();
```